# Fields of intermediate cardinality (2)

Tags: field-theory, set-theory, real-numbers

Assuming the existence of a cardinal $\aleph_0 <\mathfrak{m} < 2^{\aleph_0}$, does it follow that there is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ of cardinality $\mathfrak{m}$ containing no algebraic numbers other than the rationals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Using Zorn's lemma, choose a transcendence basis for $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$. It is not hard to show this basis has size $2^{\aleph_0}$. Now pick some subset $A$ of this basis which has size $\frak m$ and consider the field generated by $\Bbb Q(A)$.

Because no two elements of $A$ are algebraically dependent, you did not adjoin any algebraic numbers.

Comment: Thanks again, Asaf. And by the same argument, one can find a subfield of cardinality $\mathfrak{m}$ that intersects the field of algebraic numbers at any given subfield.

Comment: Yeah. You have total control over what sort of algebraic numbers you have in your field.